# How to programmatically distinguish/control Azure internal vs. outbound traffic?

Tags: .net, powershell, azure

**Background**

I'm lead architect of developer-accelerator platform called the Ball. The Ball is designed to provide authorized processing within cloud-alike scalability, running already on Windows Azure on production with web content management. The problem it solves, is to provide full-distributed scale architecture for easy plug-in developable for back-end (.NET) and front-end web (jQuery, JSON).

The platform manages data/content up to massive scales. It's native storage design is Key-Value blob-storage, so its scalability is designed to Terabyte-scale. It supports flexible communications between instances - both end-points running in Azure.

We're now in process of plugging in user-definable integrations of content - thus to the problem.

**Problem/Question**

The architecture already uses low-level request management, and it's already plugged in to monitor traffic/cost through HTTP-module/handler implementation. However I don't find any clean reference how to ensure and guarantee that network calls stay within datacenter - and in a way that I know that Azure infrastructure also agrees that traffic was within datacenter.

The current production use will cause instantly gigabyte scale daily data traffic (per customer) and we need to get this right from the moment it's launched. Given the cost-efficiency for the architecture, it will become largest component by far, if it's getting billed by outbound traffic rates.

I'm not looking to remove the costs where they do apply. If customer runs their own instance of the Ball on AWS or Azure in different datacenter, there will be outbound-traffic component - no matter what.

**Current status of the solution**

The Ball has it's authorization stack at network level. While technically instance-internal traffic could be controlled within internal network, it would logically complicate things and I believe this *should* be solved through outbound network interface level control. If there is good reference-alike answer (or we make up one in this chain) it should apply to all distributed architecture cases that have to cost-optimize network outbound traffic.

The current solutions that I've found circulate around detection of datacenter-specific traffic due to IP-address, based on lists such as this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn175718.aspx

While those kind of lists technically can be used, it's loosely coupled trust to "not-to-cause-costs" at best.

Techwise the Ball is built with .NET 4.5 and latest Azure SDK for .NET. For devops-automation the Powershell is planned on roadmap, so any Azure-management level configuration can be applied for the solution as well.

I've attached few architecture images to clarify the architecture design within single Ball and as network of distributed Ball instances.
[image: Single Instance Architecturel]
[image: Distributed Instance Network]

Answer (score 0):

I just got response from our MSFT sources, that as of today (13th of Feb 2014) no required capability is exposed from the Azure platform.

So answering about how to get this info as "platform supported" is: Not possible.

I can think already few workarounds around involving IP-address based logic (not so trustworty) or adding external registry, that can be manually checked/updated for known parties that will be calling within certain datacenter. While workarounds (hopefully) suffice for certain scenarios, they do not qualify a solution for "we share this data public, as long as you're within our datacenter".

I won't flag this as accepted answer, as it's not including even the workaround specs. I'll come back myself later to fill in how we solved it.

Comment: There exists a workaround that fullfills the requirement for "we share this data and know that you're within the same datacenter - thus it will cause us no outbound costs". It is achieved using Azure Drives (= Windows Shares) that only allow net share within same datacenter. It also simplifies sharing to "file share copies", but has additional clumsiness to setup/tear down.